# can employers see search history from just chrome login

Tags: google-chrome, history, managed

I've been working remotely, and *happened* to be looking at some *wholesome videos* after hours on my personal computer on my own personal home network when I realized that particular Chrome window with logged in as my work g-mail.

I am positive it was in incognito window because all my other Chrome windows were synched with my personal gmail, and I don't see anything I was looking at in either chrome account's history on any device and the searches I made aren't auto-populating or anything.

Anyway, are my employers (or the IT company who handles our stuff) going to be able to see my search/browser history through a managed chrome login in an incognito window, even if it was my personal computer and my own network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> are my employers (or the IT company who handles our stuff) going to be
> able to see my search/browser history ....   through a managed chrome
> login in an incognito window, ....   even if it was my personal
> computer and my own network?

The way you describe, your incognito window should be fine and they should not have anything coming to their attention.

Now if I were you, I would right away separate your work Chrome Profile from your Personal Chrome Profile.

Also consider using Chromium Edge for one of the profiles. Chrome and Chromium Edge are remarkably similar. If you can use one, you can use the other.